# MobileFirst 7.1 - Getting issue with WL.JSONStore.init when running on ios 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Since upgraded to IOS 10 JSONStore initialization fails, same thing was working fine with IOS 9 and below.

Error

```
Tried to record an true without a starting timestamp
Uncaught Exception: TypeError: cdv.exec is not a function. (In 'cdv.exec(options.onSuccess, options.onFailure, pluginName, nativeFunction, args)', 'cdv.exec' is undefined) at (compiled_code):1307
```

Comment: Please provide a sample application where this error is reproducible. In internal tests of JSONStore in iOS 10 it was found to be fully certified.

Answer (score 0):

The sample applications for iOS and Cordova iOS are both operational in iOS 10. I suggest that you will examine how these handle JSONstore and make sure the you follow suit. Otherwise, you need to provide a sample application where this error is reproducible.

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/jsonstore/